# Profiling GPU usage in C#

Tags: c#, gpu, emgucv

I am writing a C# application that is GPU accelerated using EMGU's GpuInvoke method.  I would like to profile my code and look at the load on the GPU and the amount of GPU memory I'm using, but I'm having trouble finding a good way to do that.  It seems like it should be simple, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options:

- using Performance Monitor `perfmon.exe` which is the easiest tool to use
- using tools like [GPUZ](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/)
- using a performance kit from the GPU hardware vendor like [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfkit)

Comment: The performance kit from NVIDIA didn't work for me, as far as I could tell it is only applicable to code written in CUDA (or maybe also in C++?).  But GPUZ works well, thank you.